# Java "static final" vs just "static" variable while locking

Tags: java

I have been reading about using static objects as locks and the most common example would be something like this:

```
public class MyClass1 {
  private static final Object lock = new Object();
  public MyClass1() {
    //unsync
    synchronized(lock) {
      //sync
    }
    //unsync
  }
}
```

My question is does lock have to be final? I understand it is good to put it as final to assure that nobody messes with the value, but will it work without final?

Comment: you know the answer buddy! you would like to make sure that nobody makes a new assignment to the lock reference variable.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not make the variable `final`, you may get a `NullPointerException` in the constructor of `MyClass1` if you create the instance of `MyClass1` in a different thread than the thread in which `MyClass1` was loaded.

The `final` modifier guarantees safe publication of the `lock` in a way that not having `final` does not.

Also, if it's not `final`, it could be changed, leading to you locking on the wrong object instance.

You can find out more about the guarantees that the `final` modifier provides in terms of safe publication in the [Java Language Specification Section 17.5 ("Final Field semantics")](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5), which is in chapter 17 ("Threads and Locks").

Comment: Could you add a reference which further explains the guarantees `final` provides?

Comment: @Jens I think a static final gets created when the class loads. Hence, there are no chances that a thread messes it up wrt to assignement.. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Jens Good idea, I've added it.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, it will work -- until you re-assign it. If `lock` is not final, somebody could assign another value to it (`lock = new Object()`). It's like replacing the locks in your door: if you still have the old keys, you won't be able to use the lock anymore.

Making `lock` final will prevent that from happening, so it's always a good idea to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to make sure that once the lock object is created nobody messes up with it by any means. Hence, you have to make it `constant` which we do by using `static final`. `So, by creating a constant we are making sure that our lock object is created as soon as the class is loaded and never modify that in application lifetime.`

**Bonus**:

Another way of doing same is by using `static initializer`. This is well suited in the cases where you wish to do the lock object assignment in more than one statements. An example of same below:

```
public class Test {
    private static final Test lockObject;

    static {
        System.out.println("Hello");
        lockObject = new Test();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        synchronized (lockObject) {
            //your code goes here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's more intuitive if written in a different way: it's pretty much the same as this

```
public class MyClass {
    static Lock myLock = new ReentrantLock();
    public MyClass1() {
        //unsync
        myLock.lock();
        //sync
        myLock.unlock();
        //unsync
    }
}
```

with the same consequences of `myLock` being final or not.

If it's not `final` and gets reassigned, the lock status will be irrelevant.

I'd recommend using the `Lock` class anyway.